# JavaScript Calculate total price of items

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me to type the total price of selected items.
Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tp90ur6/1/)

```
 <section id="items">
   <div class="item">Monitor <span class="price">100$</span></div>
   <div class="item">Mouse <span class="price">20$</span></div>
   <div class="item">Keyboard <span class="price">60$</span></div>
 </section>
 <section id="basket">
   <p>Total price:<span class="total_price"></span></p>
 </section>`
```

Comment: follow this https://jsfiddle.net/6tp90ur6/19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6tp90ur6/1/)

```
   var total = 0;
   $("#items").on('click', ".item", function() {        
        $(this).appendTo("#basket");
        getTotal()
   });
    $("#basket").on('click', ".item", function() {      
      $(this).appendTo("#items");   
      getTotal()
   });


  function getTotal(){
     total = 0;
     $("#basket").find('.price').each(function(i){
        total += parseInt($(this).text().slice(0,-1));
        if(i + 1 === $("#basket").find('.item').length){
         $('.total_price').text(total+'$');
       } 
     });
   }
```

Comment: When I remove all items from the `basket` it saves last item price in `.total_price`

Comment: This action happens on clicking on item. I need to type the total price of items which are on basket

Comment: I need to see the total price of items which are on basket. But I need calculation without clicking on item.

Comment: @hasratyan in this case you have to put some items inside baskate . without on click how it possible . when page load and if you have items added inside basked then you can call my getTotal() function directly inside document ready function

Comment: Pls can you help me to type the total quantity of items which are in the basket?

Comment: @hasratyan can't understand

Comment: @hasratyan can you provide fiddle ?

Comment: @hasratyan so as per new fiddle total Quantity of items: is 2 right ?

Comment: Yes, now there are 2 items. But I want to make it like total price. By clicking on item, count the quantity of items which are on the basket...

Answer (score 1):

```
var total = 0;

$("#items").on('click', ".item", function() {       
    $(this).appendTo("#basket");
    total += parseInt($(this).children().text(), 10);
    $('.total_price').text(total);
});

$("#basket").on('click', ".item", function() {      
    $(this).appendTo("#items");
    total -= parseInt($(this).children().text(), 10);
    $('.total_price').text(total);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6tp90ur6/9/)

Comment: it works perfectly, but not dynamilcy.
When I remove the `.item` from the basket, the total price isn't changing

Comment: Missed that part. It's fixed now.

Comment: Can I calculate total price of items which are in the `#basket`? I mean not to calculate the price on click on the `.item`

Comment: You can do anything. It just depends when and how you want to do it.

Comment: You now have the price updated on item add/removal from #basket. On what other actions do you want the total? Or where do you need it?

Comment: I need to see the total price of items which are on basket. But I need calculation without clicking on item

Comment: :)) if you don't click on them you don't have anything in the bag, right? so the total is 0

Comment: by clicking on the item I have action. It moves into the basket and vice versa․ But I need to see the total price of items which are on the basket... It have to change dynamically

Comment: The `total` variable holds the value.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work dynamically. Even if you add or remove items, it should work.

```js
var priceList = $('#items').find('.price');

var totalPrice = 0;

$.each(priceList, function(i, price){
  
totalPrice += parseInt($(price).text())
  
  });

$('.total_price').text(totalPrice);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="items">
    <div class="item">Monitor <span class="price">100$</span></div>
    <div class="item">Mouse <span class="price">20$</span></div>
    <div class="item">Keyboard <span class="price">60$</span></div>
</section>
<section id="basket">
    <p>Total price:<span class="total_price"></span></p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have moved '$' outside of the `.total_price` span

```
$("#items, #basket").on('click', ".item", function(){
    $($(this).parent().is('#items')?'#basket':'#items').append(this);   
    $(".total_price").text(getTotal());
});

function getTotal(){
    var t = 0;
    $('.price', "#basket").each(function(){
       t+=parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    return t;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/47fgLb0w/)